# Remove html tags with their contents using Python

Tags: python, html, regex, function, strip-tags

There is any option to remove html tags WITH their content?

I only found strip tags functions that keep text inside tags.

I want **remove tags and their contents**.

Ex: `"Teste: <b> oi</b> nome"`  will be `"Teste: nome"`

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When dealing with html parsing best would be to use beautiful soup.

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex to achieve it.

```
import re
s = "Teste: <b> oi</b> nome"
replaced = re.sub('<.*?>.*?</.*?>', '', s)
print(replaced)
```